# Как сделать dynamic json в javascript?

Tags: json, javascript

Как сделать dynamic json в javascript?

```
var abc = [{               
    d: {day:"", month:"", circle:""},
    project: {title:""},
    task: {
        system: {days: "", rev: ""},
        title: "",
        desk:""
    }
}];
```

Если пишу,

```
abc[0].d = {"day":i, "month":i, "circle":i};
```

то всё ок.

А если пишу:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    abc[i].d = {"day":i, "month":i, "circle":i};
}
```

тогда получаю `undefined d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно определить, что переменная `abc[i]` - это объект:

```
for(var i = 0, abc = []; i < 10; i++) {
    abc[i] = {};
    abc[i].d = {"day":i, "month":i, "circle":i};
}

console.log(abc);
```

Comment: мне кажется лучше так делать:

    //тут где-то определение abc, например
    var abc=[];
    for (var i = 0, i < 10; i++) {
        abc[i] = abc[i] || {};
        abc[i].d = {
            "day": i,
            "month": i,
            "circle": i
        };
    }

    console.log(abc);